# Firefox generating extra space after a div, clears on reload

Tags: html, css

I notice on 2 pages from my site (http://blazingoctopuss.com/about.html and http://blazingoctopuss.com/donate.html) firefox adds a large amount of space that clears on page reload. The other 2 main pages don't have this issue but I can't figure out what I did in the markup that would cause this.

I can't replicate the problem in any other browser. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't see any problems with that page in Firefox 5 for Mac. Please specify the version, post some code and possibly a screenshot

Comment: Seems more like a problem with firefox...

Comment: I'm getting the opposite - the space doesn't appear on first load, but it does for subsequent loads. I agree with @JMichelB - this sounds like a Firefox bug.

Comment: I don't see any space in FF 5 on PC.

Comment: Where exactly is this extra space be appearing? It looks all good to me in Firefox 5 Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The Navcontainer height changes from

```
550px to 800px
```

This is probably in javascript/jquery, somewhere that you dont know.

It occurs when you load the page the first time.